# Lightning Chart legend.autoDispose doesn't work

Tags: blazor-server-side, lightningchart

I'm working with a Lightning Chart JS example for Blazor server app. I've tried many Lightning Chart interactive examples, but I can't run "legend.setAutoDispose" or "legend.SetAutoDisposeMode". Not much help from the documentation.

For example, this doesn't work:

legend.setAutoDisposeMode ({
type: "max-width",
maxWidth: 0.20,
})

Getting an error: Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: 'U is not a function ...

Also I'm intrested to dispose some Y axes (I have three Y axes) when displaying on mobile device. Can this be done with LC js?

Comment: Hi, I'd suggest opening a separate question for the Y axis disposing, because Stack Overflow doesn't really work well when you have several questions inside same thread :)

Answer (score 0):

The error with `setAutoDisposeMode` seems to have been caused by using an older LightningChart JS version, which didn't have this feature yet.

This feature was added in v.3.1.0.

I'm not 100% sure which version your project is using, but we have updated our [Blazor template](https://github.com/Arction/lcjs-blazor-template) to use the newest LightningChart JS version 3.3.2. I hope you can update your project via this template repository and be able to use `setAutoDisposeMode` as well as other new features and improvements.

If you need help with migrating from the older LightningChart JS version, here's some possibly useful links:

- [Migration guide v.2.21 -> v.3.0.0](https://www.arction.com/wp-content/uploads/LightningChart%20JS%20v2.2.1%20to%20v3.0.0%20Migration%20Guide.pdf)
- [News](https://www.arction.com/news/) including all version releases

Comment: OK, it works now after the upgrade. Thank you.